# php artisan serve gives a blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

My application folder is `c:/wamp/www/newapp`.
When I use `php artisan serve` from the `newapp` folder the server starts at port 8000.

Of course I switch off the WAMP server when I do this however I get a blank page! I tried making a `test.html` in the `newapp/public` folder and it works if I type `localhost:8000/test.html`, but it does not go to the landing page!

For your information: when I use WAMP server and type `localhost/newapp/public` it goes to the landing page, but playing with the `routes.php` does not work when using WAMP.

My question is, how do I get to the landing page using `php artisan serve`?

My Laravel version is 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possible fixes:

- run `composer install`
- Try to run `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` in the root of your project (not sure if this works on Windows though)

If this doesn't work you can try to use [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead)

Comment: I did use composer to install Laravel from the command prompt. Tried php -S localhost:8000 but still the same result! Anyone know why it doesnt work the way it's supposed to?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using Laravel 4.2? If not try upgrading

Comment: yes. because thats the version in the lynda.com tutorial. i tried using larval 5 but it has no routing available

Comment: Laravel 5 does have route support, but the folder structure is different.
In Laravel 5 you can find your routes.php in app/Http/routes.php

I suggest you update to the latest version, it is not recommended to learn an outdated version.